# Angular Cli : How do I stop the server from sending a continuous request?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How can i stop The second request before announcing the previous results ? in **Angular Cli**

---

For example **Quotes**

This is my **quotes.component.ts :**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Quote} from "../quote.interface";
import {QuoteService} from "../quote.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-quotes',
    templateUrl: './quotes.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./quotes.component.css']
})
export class QuotesComponent implements OnInit {
    quotes:Quote[];
    loading = false;
    busy = false;


    constructor(private quoteService:QuoteService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

    onGetQuotes() {
        if (this.busy == false) {
            this.loading = true;
            this.busy = true;
            this.quoteService.getQuotes()
                .subscribe(
                    (quotes:Quote[]) => this.quotes = quotes,
                    (error:Response) =>console.log(error),
                    this.loading = false,
                    this.busy = false
                );
        }else{
            alert('continuous request')
        }
    }


}
```

As you see i set "**busy = false;**" and set an "**if**" to

> run the code if **busy == false**
>   But when I send another request, twice or more ... the server accepts all requests

How can i stop The second request before announcing the previous results ?

Comment: When is this even called, and where is the "second" request you are talking about? Also, your boolean flags are set before response has been received since this is asynchronous.

Comment: the second request is just happen when you click at submit btn

Comment: This is asynchronous, so you are setting the boolean flags immediately as `false` while the request is happening, not when it has finished :)

Comment: This link can help to understand asynchronicity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `QuoteService.getQuotes()` returns an `rxjs/Observable`, the `subscribe` method has the following signature: `Observable.subscribe([successCallback, errorCallback, completeCallback])`. The lines `this.loading = false; this.busy = false;` are part of neither `successCallback` nor `errorCallback`; they are executed immediately, and you're actually passing four parameters to `subscribe`.

Either expand the code in both callbacks to include the two lines as follows:

```
this.quoteService.getQuotes().subscribe(
    (quotes:Quote[]) => {
        this.quotes = quotes;
        this.loading = false;
        this.busy = false;
    }, 

    (error: Response) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.loading = false;
        this.busy = false;
    });
```

Or, better still, use `finally`:

```
this.quoteService.getQuotes()
.finally(() => {
    this.loading = false;
    this.busy = false;
})
.subscribe(
    (quotes:Quote[]) => this.quotes = quotes, 
    (error: Response) => console.log(error)
);
```